# LaTeXML \itemize creates weird <ul>

Tags: latexml

I'm surprised/confused by LaTeXML's handling of lists. With an example like this called `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Hello itemize:
\begin{itemize}
  \item one
  \item two
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Running the command

```
latexml test.tex | latexmlpost - --destination=test.html
```

Produces the following HTML: (snipped to the interesting bits)

```
<article class="ltx_document">
<div id="p1" class="ltx_para">
<p class="ltx_p">Hello itemize:</p>
<ul id="I1" class="ltx_itemize">
<li id="I1.i1" class="ltx_item" style="list-style-type:none;">
<span class="ltx_tag ltx_tag_itemize">•</span> 
<div id="I1.i1.p1" class="ltx_para">
<p class="ltx_p">one</p>
</div>
</li>
<li id="I1.i2" class="ltx_item" style="list-style-type:none;">
<span class="ltx_tag ltx_tag_itemize">•</span> 
<div id="I1.i2.p1" class="ltx_para">
<p class="ltx_p">two</p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</article>
```

This is strange because not only is the bullet typeset explicitly (which I wouldn't have expected), more importantly the content of the list is wrapped in `div` and `p` tags which means there's a linebreak between the bullet and the item!

[image]

Obviously that's not a problem if I'm using the latexml CSS file, but I'd like to re-use the HTML in a context in which I can't customise the CSS used.

Anyone have any ideas on how to "improve" the output here?

I'm using version

```
latexml (LaTeXML version 0.8.2; revision 644644a)
```

Comment: There are some reason to do not use `pandoc`? This program convert  your MWE in a simpler HTML file without the SPAN and DIV tags.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into pandoc. Can it deal with semi-arbitrary code like \newcommand?

Comment: Yes, the macro `\foo`defined as  `\newcommand\foo{bah}` is converted in HTML as `<span>bah</span>` (obviously losing the definition).

Comment: That was a bad example from me: it looks like pandoc treats `\newcommand` as a special case :) To be honest, I suspect that I could get pandoc to do what I needed... but I like the degree to which latexml actually understands the LaTeX source. Whether I take advantage of such things remains to be seen!

Comment: But macros  are especial cases. The are no way (afaik) to make these macros in pure HTML, nor there are equivalent HTML tags  for any macro than you can invent. Then, the more seasonable for me is  parse LaTeX definitions and apply the expanded macro. Otherwise, what should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP has seen on the [github issue](https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/issues/829), you can now use

```
latexmlpost --dest=test.html --xsltparameter=SIMPLIFY_HTML:true test
```

to get the html

```
<article class="ltx_document">
<div id="p1" class="ltx_para">
<p class="ltx_p">Hello itemize:</p>
<ul id="I1" class="ltx_itemize">
<li id="I1.i1" class="ltx_item">
<div id="I1.i1.p1" class="ltx_para">
<p class="ltx_p">one</p>
</div>
</li>
<li id="I1.i2" class="ltx_item">
<div id="I1.i2.p1" class="ltx_para">
<p class="ltx_p">two</p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</article>
```

This will skip over any optional argument to `\item[]`.  If someone wanted to mix the two, they would probably need to `\usepackage{latexml}`, sprinkle in some `\lxAddClass{simpleList}`, and create a custom xslt for latexmlpost to use.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting situation; clearly what you're asking for is the "correct" result for the case you've given. LaTeXML's more general approach is attempting to model the wide variety of things that LaTeX typically throws at it.  For example, any itemization can contain an arbitrary `\item[$a+b$]` which needs markup, rather than attribute values, hence the span for the bullet. Not to mention, the author may have redefined `\labelitemi`. Likewise, any item can contain multiple paragraphs, hence the div, p elements. So, at least that's the excuse for LaTeXML's internal XML.  How do other processors handle such cases?

I guess a solution might be for LaTeXML's xslt to examine the itemizations for non-special cases, and dumb them down. Hmm...  Really no possibility of sneaking some CSS in there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bruce! I'm guessing other tools don't do it as comprehensively as latexml :-) CSS can be placed inline in HTML elements right? I'm not saying this should happen out of the box, but maybe I can adapt the post processor to add the necessary CSS declarations in this case. (Even if it's an ugly regexp hack!)

Comment: I just tried embedding the CSS into the webform in between `<style>` tags, with no luck — is stripped out :) I'll try to boil down the required declarations to add in `<div style="...">` next…

Comment: …and either my HTML+CSS skills aren't up to scratch, or it's not really possible to do advanced CSS inline in a `style=` attribute. I worked around the problem as shown in my answer above/below.

Comment: (Odd, my reputation is too low to comment on an answer, but I can comment on a comment?)  Your solution sounds painful! OTOH, generically dumbing down the markup would lead to inconsistencies, probably should be optional. Further discussion on that is probably less of general interest, so followup on Will's github issue: [https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/issues/829]

Answer (score 1):

I think Bruce's answer that latexml's output is correct in the general sense is persuasive. For my purposes, however, I was willing to compromise in the interests of, well, having HTML that displayed sensibly without needing the associated CSS file for correct rendering.

For me, that involved using a regular expression to strip out the extra markup that causes the issue:

```
sed -ie 's/<span class="ltx_tag ltx_tag_itemize">•<\/span>//g' test.html
sed -ie 's/class="ltx_item" style="list-style-type:none;"/class="ltx_item"/g' test.html
```

In short, this simply strips out the explicit bullet and removes the directive to turn off the automatic bullet. No doubt I may need something similar for `enumerate`, but `description` works well the way it is already.